# Vim does not `--INSERT--` when I am in insert mode?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I am using `Vim` on my Ubuntu desktop computer. When I entered into the `vi` interface, the `--INSERT--` under bottom of interface.

I used: `:set showmode` and restart my `Vim`. Unfortunately, it did not effected, what is wrong with this command?

Could you tell me why `:set showmode` does not work?

Comment: Include `set showmode` in your `.vimrc`. By doing so, the option will be set every time you open Vim. Also include `set nocompatible` in `.vimrc`, preferably on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: create the file `~/.vimrc` if it doesn't exist already.

Step 2: add `set showmode` to that file and write it.

Step 3: enjoy your mode indicator in every subsequent Vim session.

Answer (score 1):

Vim / vi have quite a long history, and therefore work a bit different to how most modern applications behave. In particular, while most applications have a *Preferences* or *Settings* dialog, and will automatically persist any changes, in Vim any configuration done via `:set` is lost once you exit the editor.

The advantage of that is that you can try out various options (and Vim has a lot of them!) without having to worry about messing up one's configuration. The downside is that you have to explicitly edit your configuration. The main file is `~/.vimrc` (in your home directory, for user-specific configuration). You can create a new one or base it on `:help vimrc_example.vim` if you don't have one yet. To edit, just use

```
:edit $MYVIMRC
```

To reload it, `:source %`, or just quit and restart Vim. Ample use of comments is recommended. You can also put the file under version control. Many users publish their Vim configuration on GitHub; this also helps when you use multiple systems.

Answer (score 0):

:set showmode I tried setting it up too but there was another problem.
-- insert -- I couldn't see because the color of the letter was the same as the background of the terminal. So change the background color of the terminal to a different color.